# after composer install 403 forbidden error for magento built app

Tags: magento2, centos7

I need to reopen an app made with magento on centos so basic step :
-close the app
-command Composer install
-command php bin/magento setup:di:compile
-command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

now opening in my local environement and ... 403 forddiben you don't have permission to access / on this server.

Then I thoug permission issue then I followed this article : https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001868933-How-to-set-Magento-2-permissions-and-avoid-installation-errors - it didn't work for me 
i tried to allow chmod 777 -Rf for the root - it didn't work
i added : 

AllowOverride all
Require all granted

to my httpd.conf (I use virtual host that why the root is in www)- it didn't work

do anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I found was to uninstall everything and install again, worked but still unknow reason of the problem